# QTConcurrent triggers a signal multiple times

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a c++ qt program. So I have 2 classes. In mainwindow I have a function that fires when a button is clicked and it runs a function from the second class on another thread. When I call the function for the first time, everything is ok, but when I run the function for the second time, the function is already called twice etc.

Here is my code:
mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "secondclass.h"

#include <QFutureWatcher>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void slot(QString text);
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    secondClass* secondclass;
    QFutureWatcher<void>* futureWatcher;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QFuture>
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , secondclass(new secondClass())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(secondclass, &secondClass::signal, this, &MainWindow::slot);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    auto futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>(this);
    connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::deleteLater);
    futureWatcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run( [=]{ secondclass->func();}));
}

void MainWindow::slot(QString text)
{
    std::cout << text.toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

secondclass.h

```
#ifndef SECONDCLASS_H
#define SECONDCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class secondClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    secondClass();
    void func();

signals:
    void signal(QString text);
};

#endif // SECONDCLASS_H
```

secondclass.cpp

```
#include "secondclass.h"
#include <QString>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

secondClass::secondClass()
{
}

QString text;
std::ostringstream ss;

void secondClass::func()
{
    text.clear();
    ss << "Test\n";
    std::cout << "Test thread" << std::endl;
    text = QString::fromStdString(ss.str());
    signal(text);
}
```

Comment: do you want to send a signal and receive from another thread ?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason, on the second start, the signal is duplicated

Comment: Why do you wonder why the signal is send more than once when you do the connect on every click on the pushbutton again?

Comment: You think that signal is duplicated because `Test` is printed 2 times when you pushed the button second time?

Answer (score 2):

You should only call `QObject::connect(...)` once, every time you enter `on_pushButton_3_clicked()` you're creating another connection. Move the `connect` call to the `MainWindow` constructor, or somewhere else where it will only occur one time.

Comment: When I do this, my program crashes

Comment: You've edited your question a few times since I gave this (probably over-simplified) answer almost a month ago, so I'm not entirely sure how to help at this point. Perhaps try reducing your problem down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or asking a new question with your latest changes to your code.